# missing timing from promised value

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, autodesk-forge

So I am using Forge with View API to analyze all parts from a model which contain concrete and hide everything that is not concrete. The problem is that the properties for checking concrete are called from a DB which requires me to make it a promise. Checking for concrete is working as expected and then the problem starts. I return the Ids containing concrete, but my function which is supposed to hide it uses the Ids before the promise is resolved, so the array is empty.
console.log logs it as expected but everything else misses the timing.
My code:

```
getProperties(dbId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.gui.getProperties(
            dbId,
            args => {
                resolve(args.properties)
            },
            reject
        )
    })

}

async getConcreteIds() {
    let wallfloorids = this.getWallIds().concat(this.getFloorIds());
    let concreteIds = [];
    for (let id of wallfloorids) {
        let p1 = this.view.getProperties(id);
        p1.then(props => {
            for (let prop of props) {
                if (prop.displayCategory === "Materialien und Oberflächen" && prop.displayValue.contains("Concrete")) {
                    concreteIds.push(id);
                }
            }
        }).catch(() => {
        });
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            resolve(concreteIds)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Err", reject)
        }
    })
}


async onlyConcrete() {
    this.getConcreteIds().then(concrete => {
        debugger;
        this.viewer.isolateById(concrete)
    });
}
```

Comment: Promise that you constucted in `getConcreteIds` function is resolved almost immediately (because call `resolve(concreteIds)`). At this time array still contains no ids.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I wrote a check that checks if the length is not 0, but the promise never resolves, and it never executed my `onlyConcrete` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map an array of promises for your loop and use `Promise.all()` to resolve after all the promises in loop resolve

Something like:

```
async getConcreteIds() {
  let wallfloorids = this.getWallIds().concat(this.getFloorIds());

  let concreteIds = [];

  let promises = wallfloorids.map(id => {
    let p1 = this.view.getProperties(id);
    return p1.then(props => {
      for (let prop of props) {
        if (prop.displayCategory === "Materialien und Oberflächen" && prop.displayValue.contains("Concrete")) {
          concreteIds.push(id);
        }
      }
    });
  });

  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(_ => concreteIds)
    .catch(err => console.log("Err", err))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have problems understanding the code. So from my understanding we want to create an array of promises which all get resolved in `Promise.all`. But I dont understand how to map the id with the promise. Implementing the code returns undefined when I log it, so guess it doesnt attach it properly. If we `return p1.then`, it jumps immediately out, does it not?

Comment: `return p1.then()` returns to the [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)` callback to put that promise into the array. Does `console.log(id)` give you what is expected ?

Comment: Oh I see, `console.log(id)` below the concreteIds.push returns the 14 correct ids, 'console.log(promises)' returns  56(number of ids) resolved promises with promisevalue undefined and logging           
 `let concrete = this.getConcreteIds();`returns a pending promise

Comment: Sounds good so far. `this.getConcreteIds().then(concreteIds=>console.log(concreteIds))` should give you what you want...the fully populated array

Comment: Unfortunately it returns undefined

Comment: Or `let concreteIds = await this.getConcreteIds()`

Comment: Oh..might be because nothing returned or thrown in `catch()` that you get undefined. Throw the error again and see what happens or return something that you can recognize as coming from catch

Comment: Wait, if one promise from all the promises is rejected, then the whole thing is rejected right, because I have a promise which is always rejected

Comment: Yes. Should be seeing a log inside the catch and either need to return something (like the partial array) or throw the error again...depending on how you want the error handling to work

Comment: It was resolved by catching the error p1 gives. And my other functions did not miss timing so everything is ok now. THANK YOU SO MUCH, was blocked for a whole day by this :D